# how to remove duplicates from a set?

Tags: c++

I know sets in C++ do not allow duplicates however what I'm trying to achieve is slightly different. My program reads a data file in the form below, imports the data and does some calculation with it.

If i take a size count of the set via `set1.size()`, it will count pairs like `3    9` and `3    9` once since it does not accept duplicates. However, I also want something like `3    9` and `9    3` to be counted as one.

```
1    4
5    8
3    9
3    9
9    3
3    0
... so on
```

So in the data given above (only the 6 lines), if I did `set1.size()`, I want it to say 4. `(3,9)(3,9)&(9,3)` should only be counted once. My code is below, this is how I insert the data into the set and then I later COUT the size.

```
string in;
set<pair<int, int> > set1;
while (getline(fs, in)) {
    istringstream iss(in);
    int j, k;   
    if (iss >> j >> k) {
        set1.insert({j, k});                                    
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: does the order of (9,3) and (3,9) matter in a `pair<t1,t2>`to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think even this would work:

```
if( iss >> j >> k){
   if(j > k) set1.insert({j,k});
   else set1.insert({k,j});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own custom comparison function to a set. You can then treat the two different pairs as the same.

Something like this:

```
class MyCompare
{
public:

    bool operator () (const pair<int, int> &left, const pair<int, int> &right)
    {
        pair<int, int> orderedLeft = left;
        if (orderedLeft.first > orderedLeft.second)
            swap(orderedLeft.first, orderedLeft.second);

        pair<int, int> orderedRight = right;
        if (orderedRight.first > orderedRight.second)
            swap(orderedRight.first, orderedRight.second);

        return orderedLeft < orderedRight;
    }
};
```

Then declare your set using this:

```
set<pair<int, int>, MyCompare > set1;
```

Obviously the code should be cleaned up a bit (remove duplication etc).

Comment: With C++11: `bool operator()(const pair<int, int> &left, const pair<int, int> &right) { return std::minmax(left) < std::minmax(right); }`